# I do not understand why I get CS0120

Tags: c#

I am having one error and have searched for answers in my book and watched tutorials for this particular subject. The large gap is to indicate another class I added called `Point`

```
    class Program
    {
        private static Point another;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point origin = new Point(1366, 768);
            Point bottomRight = another;
            double distance = origin.DistanceTo(bottomRight);
            Console.WriteLine("Distance is: {0}", distance);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Point objects: {0}", Point.ObjectCount());
        }
    }
class Point { 
    private int x, y;
        private int objectCount = 0;
        public Point()
        {
            this.x = -1;
            this.y = -1;
            objectCount++;
        }
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            objectCount++;
        }
        public double DistanceTo(Point other)
        {
            int xDiff = this.x - other.x;
            int yDiff = this.y - other.y;
            double distance = Math.Sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));
            return distance;
        }
        public static int ObjectCount()
        {
            **return objectCount;** 
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to our community. Please notice that you have to post a good question in order to receive help from the others. remove unnecessary parts from your code and simplify it and of course don't put space lines instead.
if you want the others to spend time on your problem, you have to be the first one to care and spend time

Answer (score 3):

Your `ObjectCount()` method is **`static`** method while your property is not.

```
public static int ObjectCount()
```

As you are reading from a property which is not allocated in your code. So, remove the **static** keyword from the methods signature.

```
public int ObjectCount()
{
    return objectCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) please post full code in separate blocks, also please tell people where exactly you get the error;

2) my guess is that error CS0120 comes from the line: Console.WriteLine("Number of Point objects: {0}", Point.ObjectCount());

Yet again, I guess that you wanted to count all of the Point objects created. Your mistake is making objectCount an instance member.

You see, every instance of Point class will have its own objectCount, and it will always be 1 after constructor finishes. For the very same reason you can not call Point.ObjectCount() and return objectCount from it, because objectCount is not a static member, it's bound to an instance.

To fix your code, make objectCount static. That way there would be only one objectCount for all instances of Point.